# Basic command with indefined parameters

Tags: macros, citing, footnotes

I want to do a basic command called \footcite to write a text, and any number of citations to write them in the footnote.
It's basically this command `\newcommand{\footcite}[2]{\footnote{#1 \cite{#2}}}` but with 2-n parameters. An use case of this would be `\footcite{LLM like ChatGPT or BERT}{chatgpt}{bert}`,
resulting in a footnote like "LLM like ChatGPT or BERT [1] [2]"

I don't know anything about xparse or macros, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A command `\footcite` is defined. It takes 2 arguments. The second argument is a list. A loop is performed on this list with `\clist_map_inline:nn`. Here each element in the list is given by `##1` on which `\cite` is applied with a space `~` before that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \footcite { m m }
  {
    \footnote
      {
        #1
        \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
          { ~ \cite {##1} }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Some text\footcite{LLM like ChatGPT or BERT}{chatgpt,bert}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{chatgpt}
\emph{ChatGPT},
2024.
\bibitem{bert}
\emph{BERT},
2024.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```